# How can I find the right lens cap for my lens?

Tags: lens, equipment-protection, lens-cap

I own a Nikon D3000 Camera with the AF-S 18-55mm VR Kit Lens. Last week I lost the lens cap and now I want to buy a new one.

But when I went to [this online store](http://www.flipkart.com/cameras/lens-caps), I got confused with the different ranges of lens names —  LC-62, LC-78, etc.

My concern is what if I order one lens cap and it won't fit correctly on my lens?

If you guys have an D3000, can you please let me know how to find the correct lens cap names?

Comment: Have you taken your camera and lens into a camera store?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The number part of the Nikon part number for the lens cap is the filter size. (The LC stands for "lens cap".) Your lens takes a 52mm filter; you'd need an LC-52 lens cap.

Answer (score 10):

You're looking for the ø symbol with a number after it:
[image]

After you find that, you can get any lens cap that is for that diameter lens.

Comment: can someone put the image in the post for me...I can't yet...need more cred on this exchange site. thanks in advance

Comment: Done — welcome to the site.

Comment: ... if you could only replace the "yoru" with "your" 8-)

Comment: ahh sorry... Math and English is my 3 worst subjects

Answer (score 4):

Like [Stan Rogers points out](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/11037/1772), all that you need to know is the filter diameter for the lens, which should be listed in just about every data sheet or review of the lens that you can find. The AF-S DX NIKKOR 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6G VR (which I take it you mean) does indeed take a 52 mm filter according to Nikon's web site and a quick Google search.

*However*, you don't need to buy an original lens cap unless you specifically want to for some reason. There is no functional difference between an original lens cap and one of another brand. Picking up a no-name cap of the same diameter is most likely to get you exactly the same results for half the price or less.

Comment: There's usually no need to go looking that far afield -- the filter diameter is usually printed, embossed or engraved somewhere on the lens.

Comment: @Stan, good point - I didn't think of that, but it's quite true.

Answer (score 3):

Just worry about the diameter of the lens. Eg: In your case its a 52mm. Any lens can with a 52mm will work. You can even get a good quality 3rd party lens cap also. Also just in case you don't want to loose your cap again you could invest on a lens cap leash. Its a little annoying to use but works well.