# What is the difference between a Canon and Nikon lens cap?

Tags: canon, nikon, lens-cap

I found a nice project on [Kickstarter](http://www.kickstarter.com) that I would like to fund: [Camera Lens Cap Holder](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/293194835/camera-lens-cap-holder)

But it's listed that there will be 10 different lens caps sizes for the holder:

From the site (as of June 7, 2011):

> 52mm, 55mm, 72mm & 77mm for Nikon,
>   Pentax, Fujifilm, Sony, Pro-series and
>   vintage lenses
>
> 46mm, 58mm & 67mm for M4/3, Cannon and
>   Nikon lenses
>
> 40.5mm, 49mm & 62mm for M4/3, Olympus and vintage lenses

What is the difference between a Canon and Nikon lens cap, in terms of it's fitting?

Specifically, I have a 72mm lens for my Canon, so does the 72mm lens cap holder listed for the Nikon here not fit my Canon lens cap?

Comment: See also http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11036/how-can-i-find-the-right-lens-cap-for-my-lens

Comment: Very cool project, if only some of my lenses shared the same filter thread!

Comment: The brands there are really just examples. The Pentax DA Limited lenses, for example, use a 49mm thread (which is listed as m4/3, Olympus, and vintage!).

Comment: @mattdm - Actually, not many. Plus, several use a lens cap that holds to the **outer** edge of the lens.

Comment: Hm,
nice idea. My old EVF Finepix S9600 had something similar. I often miss something on my Pentax DSLR. I think, that the lens caps should be interchangeable as they works also when you use filters and the filters does not have different design for various manufacturers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Lens caps that are attached to filter thread can easily be shared between different brands. The sizes listed here are frequently used by given manufacturers. So yes, a 72mm Canon lens cap will fit a lens cap holder with 72mm filter thread, even if it appears to be "for Nikon".

Comparing lens caps of [Canon](http://shop.usa.canon.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/subCategory_10051_10051_-1_12113) and [Nikon](http://www.nikonusa.com/Nikon-Products/Photography-Accessories/Lens-Caps/index.page), Canon's lens caps are usually based on simple plain design with two release buttons on mutual sides. Nikon has those for point-and-shoots; the ones for (d)SLR lens use snap-on design (i.e. you can pinch the center to release), which is much more convenient to operate when your lens hood is on. Some [Pentax lens caps](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/buy/Lens-Caps/ci/5429/N/4232860488) are also using similar design.

Some lenses use a different mechanism for attaching a lens cap, slipped on lens hood - usual suspects for this solution are ultra-wide, fish-eye, and vintage lenses. Their lens caps are generally specially made for the lens model and cannot be used on different lenses. These lens caps do not use millimeter designation.

Comment: The question is, would you want to have an icky Nikon lens cap on your Canon lens? ;D

Comment: @Guffa good question, edited

Comment: It's beyond me why Canon does not adopt a similar lens cap to Nikon, perhaps a patented design?

Comment: I found a Nikon lens cap on the trail earlier this year.  Just so happens that it fits my Canon lens quite nicely, and I like the center-pinch design a lot better.  I'm not above improving on the original.

Comment: Sigma does the pinch on center too - so its not patented.

Comment: Not being sued is not a proof. Actually they are being sued by Nikon for more important patents involving stabilization. A number of companies keep patent portfolios to sue defensively.